# Java, How to get connection response code from HTTP POST method?

Tags: http-post, http-get

I can get data when I'm using following code:

```
    private static String getHttpPostContent(String address, String token) {    
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);

            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", token));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            return serverResponse;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Based on my documentation if error happens then server sends error 418 to tell me something wrong happened. I have no idea how to catch it?

When I'm using HTTP GET method there is a way how to check response code, like this:

```
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
...
```

is there similar way in HTTP POST method?

Comment: Did you try observing httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()?

Comment: Thanks, exactly correct. please write it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try observing `httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` ?

Comment: Did you happen to see the comments below the post?